# Trying extract data under of specific div and sub div

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get it so I can have it print the title of the book and the chapters but only each book and title.

So basically 
"The First Book of Jacob"
Chapters 1-7

instead of it iterating over all the books.

Here is the page layout (url included in python code)

```
<dl>
  <dt>Title</dt>
  <dd>
    <dl>
      <dt>Sub Title</dt>
    </dl>
  </dd>
  <dt>Title 2</dt>
  <dd>
    <dl>
      <dt>Sub Title 2</dt>
    </dl>
  </dd>
</dl>
#this continues for Title 3, Sub title 3, etc etc
```

Here is the python code

```
import requests
import bs4


scripture_url = 'http://scriptures.nephi.org/docbook/bom/'
response = requests.get(scripture_url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)

links = soup.select('dl dd dt')
for item in links:
    title = str(item.get_text()).split(' ', 1)[1]
    print title
```

Here is the output

```
Chapter 1
Chapter 2
Chapter 3
Chapter 4
Chapter 5
Chapter 6
Chapter 7
Chapter 8
Chapter 9
Chapter 10
Chapter 11
Chapter 12
Chapter 13
Chapter 14
Chapter 15
Chapter 16
Chapter 17
Chapter 18
Chapter 19
Chapter 20
Chapter 21
Chapter 22
Chapter 1
Chapter 2
Chapter 3
Chapter 4
Chapter 5
Chapter 6
Chapter 7
Chapter 8
Chapter 9
Chapter 10
Chapter 11
Chapter 12
Chapter 13
Chapter 14
Chapter 15
Chapter 16
Chapter 17
Chapter 18
Chapter 19
Chapter 20
Chapter 21
Chapter 22
Chapter 23
Chapter 24
Chapter 25
Chapter 26
Chapter 27
Chapter 28
Chapter 29
Chapter 30
Chapter 31
Chapter 32
Chapter 33
Chapter 1
Chapter 2
Chapter 3
Chapter 4
Chapter 5
Chapter 6
Chapter 7
Chapter 1
Chapter 1
```

Comment: Description of what you need isn't clear at all -there are some contradictions. Posting expected output -print result maybe- would help us understand what you *actually* try to achieve

Comment: @har07 Thank you for that, I went ahead and clarified the question as well as put the output and tried to explain it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this. First, find a book, for example, having title "The Book of Jacob" :

```
book_title = 'The Book of Jacob'
book = soup.find('a', text=book_title)
print book.text
```

Then select `<dd>` that is direct sibling of the book title, and find all corresponding chapters within that `<dd>` element :

```
links = book.parent.select('+ dd > dl > dt')
for item in links:
    title = str(item.get_text()).split(' ', 1)[1]
    print title
```

Output :

```
The Book of Jacob
Chapter 1
Chapter 2
Chapter 3
Chapter 4
Chapter 5
Chapter 6
Chapter 7
```

Answer (score 0):

just cut off the last 2 in the array, the control isnt that fine grained since there isnt any id's or names in the html tags

```
links = soup.select('dl dd dt')
for item in links[:-2]:
    title = str(item.get_text()).split(' ', 1)[1]
    print title
```

Comment: this does not seem to work for what I need.  I updated the question to clarify.  The site has more than 1 title, goes on for a while.  I need to be able to change the terms and select say title 1, or title 7 etc

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know they are always the first and second values, you can use an array reference:

```
title = links[0];
subtitle = links[1];
```

Comment: I updated my question.  I need the to be able to select the 1st, then later the 2nd, or 3rd, as it is a page with a lot of sections